# How do I integrate Woocommerce payment method to my banks checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment, checkout, gateway

i am new to woocommerce and i really need some help...My bank send me a payment checkout code and i wish to integrate it into woocommerce checkout page...

the attached checkout page requires payment parameters from woocommerce such as paymentTotal, referenceNo, currency, purchaseDescription, transactionType..etc

how can i integrate woocommerce checkout to my banks sample checkout page please?

```
<?php
    session_start();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Mastercard MIGS VAS Integration demo - checkout page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Example MIGS VAS Server Hosted Merchant Integration - Checkout Page</h1>

<form action="postrequest.php" method="POST">
    <div>
        <p>Purchase an Item</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="paymentAmount">Sale Base Units</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="paymentAmount" name="paymentAmount" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="currency">Currency</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="currency" name="currency" value="AUD"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="purchaseDescription">Description</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="purchaseDescription" name="purchaseDescription"
                           value="Shiny blue widget"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="transactionType">Transaction Type</label></td>
                <td><select id="transactionType" name="transactionType">
                    <option>authorise</option>
                    <option selected>purchase</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="referenceNumber">Reference Number</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="referenceNumber" name="referenceNumber" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="messageReference">Message Reference</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="messageReference" name="messageReference" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" id="checkOut" name="checkOut" value="Check out"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need the bank's API to make it work. Some banks use Authorize.net.

Comment: @Scriptonomy i have the banks api, [link](http://www.ssab.ws/stig-php-example-0.4.zip) .If you could please have a look at the contents of the zip file and advice please...i really need help how to integrate this piece of code into woocoomerce...the attached link (http://www.ssab.ws/stig-php-example-0.4.zip) zip file contains the checkout.php code which needs to be integrated...Your help is much appreciated...